# A lot of files are in the staging area to be committed while not present in the current directory.How do I get rid of this?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

[image]

I opened VSCode from the current directory via terminal. While I was going to initialize a repo there were more than 5K files in the staging area to be committed which are not present in the current but are in present in the Users directory. Even git status also shows 5K files in the staging area. Due to this VScode is not responding and it's shutting down

Comment: It seems you have initialized a git repository in an unexpected folder. Open git bash in the current folder and run `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`. If it prints the path to the current folder, run `cd .. && git rev-parse --show-toplevel`. It will print the wrong directory which should not be a git repository. Remove the `.git` folder  in that directory.

Comment: Thank You for solving my problem